# Override MySQL Variable from conf file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to override the variable `optimizer_switch` and change `rowid_filter=on` to `rowid_filter=off`.

The [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizer-switch/) does not provide an example.

#### Attempt #1:

###### /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/70-optimizer.cnf

```
[GLOBAL]
optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off'
```

Restart services:

```
sudo service mariadb restart
sudo service mysql restart
```

#### Attempt #2:

Same as #1 but I moved my file here `/etc/mysql/conf.d/70-optimizer.cnf`

---

I checked by logging in to mysql and executing `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "optimizer_switch";`, and I get this at both attempts:

> optimizer_switch |
> index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on,condition_pushdown_for_subquery=on,**rowid_filter=on**,condition_pushdown_from_having=on,not_null_range_scan=off

As you can see it is still turned **on**

What am I missing?

---

I tried setting it directly via `SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch = 'rowid_filter=off';` but it is still **on** if I check.

Answer (score 1):

To **Debug** it , try these :

**(D1)** : Try setting it at `mysql` prompt & ensure that the value is getting updated.
If value is not getting update , Issue is something else.

**(D2)** You should try to set it at `/etc/my.cnf` or execute `mysqld --help --verbose` & check what configurations files are getting loaded.
It looks like the files you listed are not getting loaded.

**(D3)** Try setting some other option (at `mysql` prompt & via various configuration files) & ensure that the update goes through.
If no option goes through , Issue is something else.

**(D4)** Check your MySQL server Startup Command.
Ensure that it is not using [--no-defaults](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqld-options/#-no-defaults) which will force this Issue.

Based on your findings , we can move forward.
**Current** thinking is that these configuration files are not loaded , you have to check which files are actually loaded.

How to set it at MySQL Command Prompt or through conf file :

`SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] optimizer_switch='command[,command]...';`

`set optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off';`

```
[mysqld]  
optimizer_switch=rowid_filter=off
```

[reference 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/switchable-optimizations.html)
[reference 2](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/1500012320162-How-can-I-change-the-values-of-optimizer-switch-variables-for-MySQL-)
[reference 3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#default-option-file-locations-on-linux-unix-mac)
[reference 4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#server-option-groups)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the group from GLOBAL to `mysqld`

```
[mysqld]
optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off'
```

Restart services:

```
sudo service mariadb restart
sudo service mysql restart
```